# How to upload image in wordpress post via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Objective: To Load the image after the the specific time interval of 5 Second.

Problem: The written code is perfectly working with Single.Php, but not working inside the WordPress Post.

```
    <div id="imageContainer"></div>
<script>
var img = document.createElement("img");  

img.onload = function(e) {
    var container = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
    container.appendChild(e.target);
}

setInterval( 'img.setAttribute("src","image.jpg")',5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're passing a string to `setInterval`, not code.  Pass a function instead, as in the example here. For more on the topic see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout).

```js
var img = document.createElement("img");

img.onload = function(e) {
    var container = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
    container.appendChild(e.target);
}

setInterval(function() { img.setAttribute("src", "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c2dc29e1a1ce74f25adf39e28d23a601?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG") }, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="imageContainer"></div>
```

Comment: i have tried but same results..will you please elaborate your answer.Thanks

Comment: @NiladriMukharjee I can't elaborate unless you provide more details on how specifically this code is failing for you- if you click "Run code snippet" in this answer, you can see the code working.